# How to switch to new java project immediately in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I switch to a new java project after using New... and close the remaining windows from the previous project automatically? I have to close each individual window every time, and tell Eclipse that now I want to use the new project.

Comment: Not very clear what you are asking, is it about closing all windows? Right click on any window-> Close All

Comment: Quick keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+F4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but when you right click on a window, you have an option to close all other windows.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

use cntrl+Shift+W  this short key will close the all window in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close the opened classes from one project, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>E</kbd> to  view the opened editors. Then, press the header for the column *"Path"* to sort them. Now select the ones from the ones from the previous project(holding the Shift key, as they are contiguous), and click on button *"Close selected editors"*